# How to fetch a model's relationship in a dynamic way?

Tags: c#, xamarin

So I have an application that makes use of a SQLite database. I have some methods for fetching models out of my database. I have a repository that communicaties with my database. And it looks like this:

```
public class PhotoRepository
    {

        AppDatabase db = null;

        public PhotoRepository ()
        {
            db = new AppDatabase (Constants.DatabaseFilePath);
        }

        public Photo GetPhoto(int id)
        {
            return db.GetItem<Photo>(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Photo> GetPhotos (int album_id)
        {
            return db.GetItems<Photo>().Where( x => x.Album_Id == album_id );
        }

        public int SavePhoto (Photo item)
        {
            return db.SaveItem<Photo>(item);
        }

        public int DeletePhoto(int id)
        {
            return db.DeleteItem<Photo>(id);
        }

    }
```

I am concerned about the `GetPhotos(int album_id)` method, because the method it approaches in my database class looks like the following:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T> () where T : BL.Contracts.IBusinessEntity, new ()
        {
            lock (locker) {
                return (from i in Table<T> () select i).ToList ();
            }
        }
```

As you can see, it retrieves ALL of the Photo Models from my database and after that I'm, filtering those out that corresponds to the right `album_id`.

No my question is:

How can I rewrite my method so that it ONLY fetches out the Models corresponding to the `album_id`. Or even better, how can I rewrite this method to filter any relationship on any property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve my own answer. Maybe people are interested in the result, so here it comes.

I read a post about dynamic LINQ queries. The post I am talking about can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq). So the first thing i did was making a `Filter` class that looks like this:

```
public class Filter
    {

        public enum Op 
        {
            Equals,
            GreaterThan,
            LessThan,
            GreaterThanOrEqual,
            LessThanOrEqual,
            Contains,
            StartsWith,
            EndsWith
        }

        public string PropertyName { get ; set ; }
        public Op Operation { get ; set ; }
        public object Value { get ; set ; }
    }
```

Then I made the `ExpressionBuilder` class that looks like the following:

```
public static class ExpressionBuilder 
{
    private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains" );
    private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = 
        typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type [] {typeof(string)});
    private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod = 
        typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type [] { typeof(string)});


    public static Expression<Func<T, 
    bool >> GetExpression<T>(IList<Filter> filters)
    {            
        if  (filters.Count == 0)
            return null ;

        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "t" );
        Expression exp = null ;

        if  (filters.Count == 1)
            exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
        else  if  (filters.Count == 2)
            exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
        else 
        {
            while  (filters.Count > 0)
            {
                var  f1 = filters[0];
                var  f2 = filters[1];

                if  (exp == null )
                    exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
                else 
                    exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]));

                filters.Remove(f1);
                filters.Remove(f2);

                if  (filters.Count == 1)
                {
                    exp = Expression .AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]));
                    filters.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
    }

    private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
    {
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);

        switch (filter.Operation)
        {
        case  PhotoWapp.DL.Filter.Op.Equals:
            return Expression.Equal(member, constant);

        case  PhotoWapp.DL.Filter.Op.GreaterThan:
            return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);

        case PhotoWapp.DL.Filter.Op.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

        case PhotoWapp.DL.Filter.Op.LessThan:
            return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);

        case PhotoWapp.DL.Filter.Op.LessThanOrEqual:
            return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

        case PhotoWapp.DL.Filter.Op.Contains:
            return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);

        case PhotoWapp.DL.Filter.Op.StartsWith:
            return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant);

        case PhotoWapp.DL.Filter.Op.EndsWith:
            return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);
        }

        return null ;
    }

    private static BinaryExpression GetExpression<T>
    (ParameterExpression param, Filter filter1, Filter  filter2)
    {
        Expression bin1 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter1);
        Expression bin2 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter2);

        return  Expression.AndAlso(bin1, bin2);
    }
}
```

Then I added the method `GetItems<T>(List<Filter> filters)` that looks like the following:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T> (List<Filter> filters) where T : BL.Contracts.IBusinessEntity, new ()
    {
        lock (locker) {
            var deleg = ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<T> (filters).Compile ();
            return (from i in Table<T>().Where(deleg) select i).ToList();
        }
    }
```

And to retrieve the records I need, I used the following code.

```
public IEnumerable<Photo> GetPhotos (int album_id)
    {
        List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter> () { 
            new Filter{
                PropertyName = "Album_Id",
                Operation = Filter.Op.Equals,
                Value = album_id
            }
        };
        return db.GetItems<Photo>(filters);
    }
```

Now I can filter nicely on all properties I need! The nice part about this solution is that I can use any class and property to filter on.

I hope this is useful to somebody!